# Making a DAX statement in Power BI for counting

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out DAX language for Excel and Power BI. 
Currently I'm facing a problem when trying to make measurements. I have 2 columns, Resign and Active.
I want to count the rows where the combination is: Resign=1 and active=0.
Do you know how to make this measurement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is difficult help you without any data, but if you have the Table 1 for example and the columns that you describe, can do it:

```
Combination = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table 1'),FILTER('Table 1',AND('Table 1'[Resign]=1, 'Table 1'[Active]=0)))
```

Please tell me if this help you!

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the statement says "doesn't expect FILTER". And then all the words following up aren't expected as well. Is the word FILTER placed correctly in this statement?

Comment: Yes, already tested with some mock data in a powerBI report. you are testing also there? Can you specify the error message please

Comment: The syntax for "table 1" is incorrect it says.
Changed table 1 in Power BI to the correct tablename from my database.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @Juliette - Are you using the correct delimiter? Try using ; in stead of  ,

Comment: It depends on the region language of your powerBI app, if you change that it works?

Comment: Happy to say it works. I had to use indeed the ; instead of ,. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

In this case the FILTER-function is not necessary. (referring to the accepted answer). Just using CALCULATE is more efficient. Like so:

```
Combination = 
     CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table 1' ); 'Table 1'[Resign] = 1; 'Table 1'[Active] = 0)
```